# Facebook API - implementing friends invitation like on Quora

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I use Facebook API to implement this feature I saw on Quora to invite Facebook friends?

Last time I checked, it seems like Facebook doesn't have anything related to this in the Graph API.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that in Facebook API. You have to implement your own. You can get friends link by using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=friends.fields(link)&access_token={accesstoken}
```